# Apache JMeter:Using post method load testing

Tags: apache

Actually I am using Apache JMeter newly.I want to use POST method for my .net project log-in page for load testing it shows error.
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the below links:

**Recording Scenario**
http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/record.html

**Correlation (extract & pass parameters between pages)**
http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html

hope this will help..